# SSRS. Page break between tables (tablix) issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-tablix

I have SSRS report with few tables (tablix control) inside. Tables are independent (but uses the same datasouce with different filters) and goes one after another in the report:

```
Report header
Table1
Table2
Table3
...
TableN
```

In case some table contains 0 rows I hide it. 
**What i need to do** is to show each table on separate page.

For this I set page break to "End" for each table except last one. So each table is show on separate page.

**Here is an issue:**
In case last table contains no data it's hidden but previous table inserts page break and I get report with last page blank.
Please let me know how can I fix the issue so I don't have blank pages and each tablix is located on separate page (tables with no rows should be hidden).

Thanks beforehand,

-Petro

Comment: Remove the page break the penultimate table. In the last table, put page break before the table, if any value.

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the **PageBreak** -> **BreakLocation** property of each Tablix to **Start** except for the first Tablix.